# Can I travel to Romania directly with a Bulgarian short stay (tourist) visa

Tags: romania, bulgaria

I am an Indian passport holder. I have a workshop to attend to in Bucharest. But since a quick visa appointment was not available for Romania, I took a Bulgarian short stay visa appointment which was available.

My visa is still under processing. My question is -

1. Can I enter Romania with Bulgarian tourist visa?
2. Can I directly travel to Romania with Bulgarian tourist Visa, or do I need to travel to Bulgaria first and then proceed to Romania?

Romanian foreign affairs website mentions that we do not need a visa if we have bulgarian/croatian/cyprus tourist visa. But many have questioned the validity of this stating that the info is not timely updated on this website. Please help.

https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040

Comment: Yeah, sort of. But thanks for answering again my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I enter Romania with Bulgarian tourist visa?

Yes, you can

TIMATIC (the database that airlines use for documentation) states:

> ### Romania - Destination Visa
>
> #### Visa Exemptions
>
> Passengers with a “C" visa issued by Bulgaria or Cyprus, valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.

> Can I directly travel to Romania with Bulgarian tourist Visa

Yes, you can, and it's compulsory if you have a single entry visa

A single entry visa becomes invalid as soon as you have used up that entry and leave the country.

Comment: The problem might be to get the visa if you do not have plans to visit the country you apply from.

Comment: Interestingly, a singly-entry Schengen visa is not valid for entry to Romania (you need a dual- or multiple-entry visa), but according to the MAE page linked in the question, this restriction does not appear to apply for Bulgarian or Cypriot visas.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It helps. @Nicolas.